# Unable to understand ASP.NET regular expression example

Tags: asp.net

I am going through the documnetation of ASP.NET on Regular Expressions where I stuck at following expression

> ^[0-9]{5}$

The Input (Mathches) are, *11111, 12345, 55555*
Now, from my understanding , first and third are correct (First character can be 0-9 and there must be five occurrences of that character). Please make me understand how second is a valid match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{5}` means that the *match* must be repeated, and `[0-9]` matches any digit. So this matches *any* 5 digits, not especially 5 *identical* digits.

Comment: Understood.. One more question .. Why  **.***  accepts no character at all ( Also was on the documentaion ).

Comment: The `*` means "0 or more matches". Instead you could use a `+` for "1 or more".